# read contents from a file to form sql statement in java

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have a file which has contents like:

```
employee firstname lastname dob address ...
department departmentname numberofemployees departmenthead ...
.
.
.
```

here the first word of each line is the name of table followed by certain number of fields. What I want is to read the first word of each line and if say the first word is `employee` then read the fields following this word till the end of the line and form the sql `select` statement based on these field. I am using below code to read in the lines and see if first word is a particular match but I am unable to proceed ahead to get the desired fields and form the `select` statements. I want to do this for any arbitrary table name

```
StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
    sql.append("select ");

    File file = new File("abc.txt");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    StringTokenizer st = null;
    while(scanner.hasNextLine())

        String lines = scanner.nextLine();
        if(lines.startsWith("employees"))
           //get the following fields till line ends
           //functionality here which I am unable to get
```

**NOTE:** I want to achieve the above goal by the best possible way and not by just using `Scanner`. If there is some better way to do this then do provide me that.

Comment: [String.split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) maybe?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose can you provide example of how can I use String.split for above task?

Comment: `String[] tokens = lines.split("\s")`

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose What I meant was that how do I read following fields till the end of the line  after the first word if it matches a search word and form the sql select

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I apologize if this is a simple question. I am new at this and hence dont have much idea about it

Answer (score 0):

I will first give you an answer on how to read a file without using scanner in an effective way. 
You can read a file line by line using BufferedReader.readLine() function. After this , you can tokenize the string since each words are separated by space. You can use the resulting string array to construct your sql.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
// process the line.
String[] splited = line.split("\\s+");
//use splited to construct your sql.   
}  
br.close();
```

Your second questions is exactly how to construct a sql statement. Now that each words are now in a string array, you can very easily contruct an sql string using stringBuilder.append();

```
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder("select "); 
String tablename =  splited[0];
for(int count=1 ; count < splited.length; line++)
{
    //construct the remaining sql 
    //firstname,lastname,... from 
}

//append the table name here after the loop.
```

Comment: When I do `for(int count=1 ; count < splited.length; count++){sql.append(splited[count]);sql.append(",");}` then I get `,` after the last field name also like `select abc,def, from table`. How do I remove the `,` after the last field name?

Comment: Check the Java docs for StringBuilder. You can find methods like StringBuilder.delete() or deleteCharAt(). Use these methods to remove the trailing '&' character

Answer (score 0):

As you already have read the *whole line* with the statement

```
String lines = scanner.nextLine();
```

you can simply split this line on the spaces to get each word:

```
String[] tokens = lines.split("\\s+");
```

Then you are able to access the tokens with a simple

```
tokens[0]
tokens[1]
...
```

Now it obviously depends on how the lines are structured. Is there a fix structure? Is it dynamic? If the structure is fix, you can simply access the array elements with the index you know. If it is a dynamic structure you must loop over the array and maybe do some more checkings.

Something else: You should rename your variable *lines* to simply *line* as it does not contain several lines.